# How to decrypt an undecryptable micro SD card?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, sd-card, encryption

I encrypted my micro SD card and used it (and encrypted/decrypted it) without issue during some months. But one day, without explanation, my micro SD card is no more decryptable: the encrypt screen at Android startup (or SD card inserting) is loading unending or showing "0Mb/0Mb - 100%" and micro SD card still unavailable and invisible.

When I connect the SD card directly to PC or Mac, files tree is browsable, files are visible but unreadable.

I tried some softwares like Android File Transfer or Android Data Recovery (Wondershare Dr.Fone for Android), without success.

I don't want to reset my phone because I will lose all my micro SD card data. Is there a way to recover data from corrupted and undecryptable micro SD card?

- Phone : Samsung Galaxy 7 (SM-G930F)
- Android : Marshmallow 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I finally find a solution in an [*recovery-android.com* comment by *vid971*](https://www.recovery-android.com/tips/encrypt-decrypt-sd-card.html#comment-2956453549) :

> 1. Go to Lock Screen and Security and select None and Keep Fingerprints. You will then be asked for setting up a password.
> 2. Remove the SD Card from the phone and Reboot.
> 3. When phone has rebooted put your SD Card back in. You will have windows prompts, for you Sim card Pin and Mobile Data usage, and after
>      that you'll be on the Encrypt SD Card page. Click Encrypt. As your
>      card is already encrypted it will be fast.
>
> From then your SD Card should be recognised again and usable.